# Why Facebook 'post date' is greater than the 'post commented date' in R?

Tags: r, facebook, r-package

I'm trying to retrieve all the data about the specific post. For some posts, I encountered that the commented date is earlier than the created date. When I check that manually in facebook, I found that the data retrieved through Rfacebook was wrong.

The code used was

```js
library(Rfacebook)
fb_oauth<-fbOAuth(app_id="app id", app_secret ="app secret",extended_permissions = TRUE)
fb_post<-getPost("post id",fb_oauth,n=100,comments = TRUE,likes = TRUE,n.likes = 100,n.comments=100)
```

The result I had obtained in RConsole was

[image: Post Commented Date earlier than the Post Date]

Can any of you help me on this? How can one comment on the post even before it is created? I couldn't able to identify where the mistake was happening?. Some of the  post `id`'s which had these problems are

```
153542981344073_1159481850750176,
153542981344073_1147835821914779,
153542981344073_638451442853222,
153542981344073_456937087671326,
153542981344073_429242860440749
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the data. The comment date can be earlier than the post date.

For the post with id `153542981344073_1159481850750176`, it's a "updated their cover photo" post. The sequence of events is as follows:

- Photo is uploaded on 9 Jan
- Comment is posted on 11 Jan
- Cover photo is set to the uploaded photo on 22 Feb

The post's `created_time` is the third date, not the first.

Comment: Thanks for your help Code. I needs to check the possible ways to retrieve the first date.